# How to get current object state to different module in python using import

Tags: python-3.x, oop, project

```
class Catalog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.different_book_count = 0
        self.books = []

def accessCurrentCatalog(self):
        return self

class Library:
    def __init__(self,name, location, age, aadhar_id,emp_id):
        super().__init__(name, location, age, aadhar_id)
        self.emp_id = emp_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + self.location + self.emp_id


    def accesCurrentCatalog(self):   
        catalog = Catalog().accessCurrentCatalog
        return catalog


    def addBook(self,name,author,publish_date,pages):
        catalog = self.accesCurrentCatalog()
        catalog.addBook(name,author,publish_date,pages)
```

i have two classes the catalog class and the library class i have created the object of catalog class and perfomed some operation within catalog class methods and i want to use the same object with all the operation perfomed in the librarian class to perform futher operation while maintaining those states 
i have tried the above method but it didn't work out
both the above classes are in different modules or files...
... please help me out with this thank you...

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're attempting to accomplish here. Are you trying to create a child class from a parent class in another python file? Or are you simply trying to create an object from said class?

Comment: both the classes the librarian class and the catalog class both are independent and both resides in the different file but have common function named let say addBook()  so using catalog class object i am calling addBook function which will add the book in the list now after that when i call the same addBook() using librarian class present in different file that it is creating the new object of catalog class and initializing the list with empty list not the added list by the catalog objects......

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something called inheritance.
Let's say your Catalog class is in a file named catalog.py and looks something like this.

```
class Catalog:
    def __init__(self, name, location, age, aadhar_id, emp_id):
        self.different_book_count = 0
        self.books = []

    def accessCurrentCatalog(self):
        # do stuff
        pass

    def addBook(self, name, author, publish_date, pages):
        # do stuff
        pass
```

You can import that class and create a child class from it using `super().__init__()`
That looks something like this.

```
from catalog import Catalog

class Library(Catalog):
    def __init__(self, name, location, age, aadhar_id, emp_id):
        super().__init__(name, location, age, aadhar_id, emp_id)
        self.emp_id = emp_id
        self.name = name
        self.location = location

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + self.location + self.emp_id
```

You now have no need for adding an addBook method to the Library class since it already has inherited one from Catalog.

You can now create an instance of the library class with

```
my_lib = Library('Some Name', 'Some Location', 69, 'Some ID', 'Some Emp')
```

If you wish to use the `accessCurrentCatalog` method you can simply call `my_lib.accessCurrentCatalog()` since it inherited that method from Catalog.

If you want to call it from within the class you simply call `self.accessCurrentCatalog()`